# React bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Есть код реакта

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './count.css';


export default class Count extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <div>
                <Button id="start" variant="primary" size="lg">
                    START
                </Button>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

И хочу изменить размер кнопки в бутстрапе, либо текст подвинуть при помощи `css`. Это можно как-то сделать? Или в бутстрапе всё изначально заложенно так что нельзя ничего поменять. Пробовал и `class` и `id` не выходит

Вот код с `css` файла

```
.start {
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: .start - это класс, а у вас id="start".

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
return (            
        <div className="App">
            <Button className="start" variant="primary" size="lg">
                START
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
```

CSS:

```
.App .start {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```